# How to start a mvn spring-boot:run and then run wget?

Tags: bash, maven, wget

I'd like to use wget to make a static page out of my spring boot app.

Therefore, I've built a bash script:

```
mvn spring-boot:run  &

wget localhost:8080 --directory-prefix=./docs/ --no-host-directories --recursive --convert-links --adjust-extension
```

However, Maven does not start the spring boot app before wget tries to get the links. I tried to use `wait` but then wget did not start its job at all.

Comment: Use `&&`: `mvn spring-boot:run  &&  wget localhost:8080...`. This will run wget after mvn is complete.

Comment: note that the solution proposed by sam will not start wget if maven fails. If that's not a behaviour you want, simply remove the `&` in your 1st line or use `;` to separate the instructions. That way, the commands will be executed sequentially, wether the 1st command succeeds or fail.

Comment: @samthegolden Unfortunately your suggestions result in the start of the spring-boot app. The wget is not reached at all.

Comment: @Aserre The same is true for your suggestion.

Comment: Oh, I see. The app continues running once the compilation is done, is that right ? You want to run your script after the compilation is done ? Could you tell us if there is a specific message displayed when the app starts launching ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The app launches Tomcat. Thus, I now used the following code to wait till Tomcat is ready and then run the wget
`mvn spring-boot:run &`

    `( echo "Waiting... Tomcat to launch on 8080..."`

    `while ! nc -z localhost 8080; do`
      `sleep 0.1 # wait for 1/10 of the second before check again`
    `done`

    `echo "Tomcat launched" &&`

    `wget localhost:8080 --directory-prefix=./docs/ --no-host-directories --recursive --convert-links --adjust-extension )`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by waiting for Tomcat to launch and then execute the wget:

```
mvn spring-boot:run &

    ( echo "Waiting... Tomcat to launch on 8080..."

    while ! nc -z localhost 8080; do
      sleep 0.1 # wait for 1/10 of the second before check again
    done

    echo "Tomcat launched" &&

    wget localhost:8080 --directory-prefix=./docs/ --no-host-directories --recursive --convert-links --adjust-extension )
```